# Coded UI - Assertion fails to detect proprietary WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a problem with Coded UI tests where assertion mechanism is unable to detect type of proprietary WPF control and detects it as custom even though it isn't. For example I have following structure:

```
<Window>
 <Grid>
  <Label x:Name="label1" Content="MyLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" Margin="233.933,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

When I use assertion tool to create an assert then this label is detected as custom control (even in the assertion tool) and then following code is generated for the label:

```
WpfCustom uILabelCustom = this.UIMyFancyTestAppMicrosWindow.UIItemTabList.UIMainWindowxamlTabPage1.UIMainWindowxamlPane.UIItemPane.UIItemWindow.UISplitViewContainerClient.UIMainWindowxamlWindow.UIItemPane.UIItemPane1.UIItemWindow.UIItemPane.UIRemoteUIElementHoldeWindow.UIRemoteContentHolderPane.UIWindowCustom.UIGridCustom.UILabelCustom;
```

I must be doing something obviously wrong. I'm thinking about writing a custom handler for them but that's not the preferred way since for the recording itself all controls are properly mapped to WPF controls. I'm using currently Enterprise VS2017 on VM Win7. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is MyLabel derrived from CustomLabel?

Comment: Nope, definition looks like:
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields")]
        internal System.Windows.Controls.Label label1;

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not. So, it seems that I will end up with custom handler for assertions to workaround this problem